# Copy one file structure to another using Redis in javascript services

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am working with redis, where I am creating new json file in redis if want to copy the exact same file and folder showing in redisinsights not working for me, my code is as below

This is for Create new data in Redis

```
static async create({
  baseData,
  newData
}) {
  if(!newData || !baseData) {
    throw new CustomError("Data is insufficient.");
  }
  if(await hasData(newData)) {
    throw new CustomError("Data is already present");
  }
  const baseDataConfig = await getData(baseData);
  baseDataConfig.parentData.push(baseDataConfig.DataName);
  baseDataConfig.DataName = newData
  baseDataConfig.isDisabled = false
  return await createData(baseDataConfig);
}
```

And to copy I am doing something like

```
static async copy({
  baseData,
  newData
}) {
  if(!newData || !baseData) {
    throw new CustomError("Data is insufficient.");
  }
  if(await hasData(newData)) {
    throw new CustomError("Data is already present");
  }
  
  const keys = await getKeys(baseData)

  console.log("Keys ", keys)
  const baseDataConfig = await getData(baseData);
  baseDataConfig.DataName = newData;
  baseDataConfig.isDisabled = false;
  return await copyData(baseDataConfig);
}
```

I am getting data of using command `>keys **CUSTOM_DATA**` but don't know how to perform copy operation here.